# Unable to boot Juno

Tags: julia

I've been trying for the longest time to work with the Juno IDE, and I've always stumbled upon a problem with the GLPK package, which basically was THE package I was needing to use. I tried uninstalling both Julia and Atom, and installing their most recent versions. Upon booting Julia via Atom, this is what I got:
Starting Julia...
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: shift! not defined

Please, help me.

Comment: Why not use commmand line?

Comment: Which julia version are you trying to use? When exactly do you get the error? `unshift!` and `shift!` have been renamed to `pushfirst!` and `popfirst!` in Julia 0.7 and 1.0. Maybe the package you are trying to use is not compatible with julia v1.0 yet.

Comment: If it is Juno that gives the error then maybe the `Atom` package you are trying to use is outdated. It should work on 1.0 I believe. Try `] update` in REPL.